# Geometrical proof for $PA+PB+PC\le3R$, where $P$ is the orthocenter and $R$ is the circumradius

Tags: geometry, triangles

$ABC$ is an acute angled triangle, where $P$ is the orthocenter, and $R$ is the circumradius. I want to show that  $PA+PB+PC\le 3R$ geometrically, that is without using trigonometry. I have a trig solution, but I want to know whether we can do it by pure geometry.

[image]

Note: In the image, the direction of the inequalities should be the opposite.

Comment: you have typos in the direction of your inequalities.

Comment: Could you fix the notation? In literature, we usually have $H$ for the orthocenter and $O$ for the circumcenter.

Comment: @achillehui Sorry, its tough to change the image, but I have added a note :)

Comment: @Sawarnik no problem, a note is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. Due to the Euler theorem, $O,G,H$ are collinear and $HO=3\,GO$.

This implies that if we take $O$ as the origin, the vector equation:
$$ H = A+B+C $$
holds. By applying the triangular inequality:
$$ OH = |H| \leq |A|+|B|+|C| = OA+OB+OC = 3R.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** the identity $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + PA^2 + PB^2 + PC^2 = 12R^2$ is useful.

Comment: How do you derive this geometrically? Besides, how to proceed with his? :O